# Obtener rowIndex en una grilla - Ext JS

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, spring, extjs

Estoy tratando de obtener el `rowIndex` dentro de una columna de una grilla para así obtener un dato en particular del Store. La columna es `Conciliadas`. El problema es que al momento de utilizar la función `renderer`, el `rowIndex` no lo identifica o lo entrega de forma errónea a la variable `rec` que he creado, ya que cuando trato de obtener el dato me sale un error de *undefined*.

Esta es la grilla:

```
var grid = new Ext.grid.Panel({
    viewConfig: {
          loadMask: true
      },
    store : store,
    frame: false,
    forceFit: true,
    border: true,
    loadMask: true,
    viewConfig: { forceFit: true },
    selModel : smrow,
    id:'grilla',
    autoSizeColumns: true,
    height: 500,
    columns : [{
        header : "Cliente",
        dataIndex : 'com_nombre',
        sortable : true,
        align : 'left',
        width :100
    },
    {
        header : "N° Trx",
        dataIndex : 'total_trx',
        sortable : true,
        align : 'left',
        width :100
    },
    {
        header : "Conciliadas",
        dataIndex : 'cant_con',
        sortable : true,
        align : 'left',
        width :100,
        renderer:function(record, rowIndex ){
            var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
            return record + ' -> '+rec.get('id_comercio');
        }
    },
    {
        header : "Pendientes",
        dataIndex : 'cant_pen',
        sortable : true,
        align : 'left',
        width :100
    },
    {
        header : "Desconocidas",
        dataIndex : 'cant_des',
        sortable : true,
        align : 'left',
        width :100
    },
    {
        header : "Liquidadas",
        dataIndex : 'cant_liq',
        sortable : true,
        align : 'left',
        width :100
    },
    {
        header : "Monto S/.",
        dataIndex : 'monto_total',
        sortable : true,
        align : 'left',
        width :100,
        renderer:function(r){
            return (r>=0?'$':'- $') + Ext.util.Format.number(Math.abs(r),'0,000');
        }
    },
    {
        xtype: 'actioncolumn',
        align: 'center',
        items: [
        {
        icon: 'images/ojo-icono.png',
        handler: function (grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {

            var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
             window.location.href = '/Monitor/mp_cliente_detalle.htm?id_comercio=' +rec.get('id_comercio');
            }

        }

        ]
    }],
    bbar: new Ext.toolbar.Paging({
        store : store,
        displayInfo: true
    }), 
    tbar: [{

        },
        '->',
        {
        text: 'Exportar',
        icon:'images/icon_excel.gif',
        handler: function(){
                 window.location.href = 'list_dashboard_cl_csv.htm';
        }
    }]
});//fin grid
```

Por otra parte tengo otra columna más abajo de tipo `actioncolumn` con la diferencia que en vez de hacer un `renderer` hago un `handler`, pero dentro utilizó la misma función y funciona correctamente. Realmente no logro entender por qué en un lado funciona y en otro no.

Otro detalle es que si en vez de poner `rowIndex` como parámetro al momento de realizar el `grid.getStore().getAt()` pongo un `0` (`getAt(0)`), funciona bien.

Comment: ¿Puedes crear un fiddle con el código de ejemplo para trastearlo?